# Can Sikuli be used for moble web testing?

Tags: testing, mobile, mobile-website, sikuli

I know Sikuli is used for mobile apps testing, has anyone used it for mobile web testing with iOS Safari or Android Browser on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

I used Sikuli for testing mobile applications (not only web).

It worked this way (all actions are performed using Sikuli):

1) launch phone emulator;

2) deploy application (if needed);

3) launch application;

4) run test cases (click somewhere, enter text, swipe, check if you get what expected etc);

5) close application;

6) close emulator.

What I liked - it is possible to perform swipe and/or drag-and-drop using Sikuli.